# How to change type of Tenant in wso2 Carbon

Tags: api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

WSO2 API Manager supports the following methods for sharing resources among tenants:

1. Private Jet mode
2. Separation at hardware level
3. Separation at JVM level
4. Native multitenancy

How I use one of theses types in the wso2 carbon?

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. Do you want to know how to use those methods in WSO2 API Manager? or in Carbon Kernel?

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot, I need to create a phisical separation in API Manager but this feature is the Carbon.